# How to interpret Odds ratios

Tags: odds-ratio

If the OR of developing dementia when living with people versus living alone is 0.36 (95% CI 0.16-0.80) what would be the OR of developing dementia when living alone versus living with people?

Would it be 1/0.36?

Comment: Simple interpretation should be: 1) The probability of developing dementia when living with people is $0.36$ times that of developing dementia when living alone.        

2) We are 95% confident that the true probability of developing dementia when living with people is between $0.16$ and $0.8$ times that of developing dementia when living alone.

Comment: Taking the reciprocal is correct. You can also do that for the limits of the confidence interval.